# Corona restore inapp purchases not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've uploaded an App on Apple App Store.
Now I am testing its updated version when I buy this App, it works fine but when I try to restore I am getting this error.

```
May 30 16:30:47 Altafs-iPa pandamath[909] <Warning>: Loading product list
May 30 16:30:47 Altafs-iPa pandamath[909] <Warning>: Product list loaded
May 30 16:30:47 Altafs-iPa pandamath[909] <Warning>: Country: IN
May 30 16:30:47 Altafs-iPa pandamath[909] <Warning>: Found 0 valid items 
May 30 16:30:47 Altafs-iPa pandamath[909] <Warning>: Item com.tinytapps.pandamath.fullpack is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
store.restore()
```

for restoring and

```
if event.transaction.state == "restored" then

end
```

block in your transaction callback, there shouldn't be any problem.